# How to automate installing an ISO in a VM?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, virtualization

We're trying to develop CI/CD processes to automate testing and installing our builds. Ya know, as one does in DevOps.

The end result of our build process are ISOs that use Red Hat Kickstart to install RHEL + our software. Today we burn the ISOs to DVD and install them on bare metal hardware. I would like to some how install and test these ISOs on virtual machines as part of our CI process. Something like:

1. Push commit to GitLab.
2. GitLab CI process runs.
3. Generates an ISO.
4. Creates a half dozen VMs via Ansible/Vagrant/something else??
5. Installs ISO in each VM.
6. Runs a smoke test on each VM to verify that it boots and our software runs.

I'm not really sure how to do 4, 5, and 6. What tools should we be using? Welcome any tips or advice... even just names of automation tools to look into.

Comment: Hi John, if you found that the answer did not fully address all your questions, or you have further questions, please update the questions and I will try to update my answer.

Comment: It's been 3 years - how is your virtualization journey going?

Answer (score 1):

If you're into RHEL you could look into running oVirt ( https://ovirt.org/ ). This will enable you to manage host machines, VMs and virtually anything in between through Ansible.

What you need is oVirt on top of CentOS or similar, on a baremetal machine. This/these machine(s) will host your new VMs and your so-called Hosted Engine (i.e. the oVirt virtualization management engine run from within a VM running on the hosts themselves to ensure high availability and flexibility), and then you just need Ansible and the oVirt Python SDK.

Once you have this, it's "as simple as" creating Ansible playbooks and using the oVirt Ansible modules https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_cloud_modules.html#ovirt

Comment: Ps: the oVirt mailing list is very active (tens of emails daily) and helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the recommendation. We're going to be looking at oVirt--and other solutions--in our next sprint to see what's viable. I apologize for the long delay. I know "weeks" is a long time to wait on Stack Exchange!